# Netsuite webservices in C#

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am working on C# program to upload image file to netsuite. Can anybody help me how to invoke netsuite script(written in 
java script)  in C# because I can find upload api only in netsuite script. Is there any webservices or functions
 in netsuite  to upload image file in netsuite ?

Comment: try explore netsuite developer resources at http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/dev-resources.shtml

Comment: I had gone through the link already, I could not find anything helpful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upload a file directly with SuiteTalk. Examples below are written in C#.

Call the below methods like this:

```
uploadFile(@"SERIAL_NUMBERS.csv", "csv", "123456");
```

Methods:

```
public static void UploadFile(string filename, string filetype, string folderId)
    {

        var sFileName = filename;

        var sNsFileName = filename;

        var sFileType = filetype;

        var sFolderId = folderId;

        var uploadFile = new com.netsuite.webservices.File { attachFromSpecified = true, attachFrom = FileAttachFrom._computer };

        if (sFolderId != null)
        {
            var folderRef = new RecordRef { internalId = sFolderId };
            uploadFile.folder = folderRef;
        }

        // Specify the NetSuite filename
        if (sNsFileName != null)
            uploadFile.name = sNsFileName;

        uploadFile.fileTypeSpecified = true;
        if (sFileType != null)
        {
            if (sFileType.Trim().ToLower().Equals("plaintext"))
                uploadFile.fileType = MediaType._PLAINTEXT;
            else if (sFileType.Trim().ToLower().Equals("image"))
                uploadFile.fileType = MediaType._IMAGE;
            else if (sFileType.Trim().ToLower().Equals("csv"))
                uploadFile.fileType = MediaType._CSV;
            else
                uploadFile.fileType = MediaType._PLAINTEXT;
        }
        else
            uploadFile.fileType = MediaType._PLAINTEXT;

        uploadFile.content = LoadFile(sFileName);

        // Invoke add() operation to upload the file to NetSuite
        var response = Service.add(uploadFile);

        // Process the response
        if (response.status.isSuccess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "\nThe file was uploaded successfully:" +
                "\nFile Record key=" + ((RecordRef)response.baseRef).internalId +
                "\nRenaming file");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file was not uploaded. Please notify the NetSuite team of the following error:");
            DisplayError(response.status.statusDetail);

        }
    }

    private static byte[] LoadFile(String sFileName)
    {
        byte[] data;

        try
        {
            FileStream inFile;
            using (inFile = new FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                data = new Byte[inFile.Length];
                inFile.Read(data, 0, (int)inFile.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error creating stream or reading from it.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             return null;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: How can I invoke add operation as it takes Record as parameter and not file

Comment: The code I provided is working production code :) You shouldn't need to make any alterations.

Comment: No it is not working for me. The is error: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ExcelWorkbook2.com.netsuite.webservices.File' to 'Record'